# Not able to start phpmyadmin on AMPPS

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using AMPPS and I simply cannot access phpmyadmin why I try to access it through : http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

I get these errors:

Error
MySQL said:

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I tried googling it but no luck I can't access phpmyadmin page at all.

Any suggestions..?

I have also notice these error messages at the bottom of my phpinfo:

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/lib/extensions/ext/mysqli.so' -
>   dlopen(/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/lib/extensions/ext/mysqli.so, 9):
>   Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib Referenced from:
>   /Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/lib/extensions/ext/mysqli.so Reason: image
>   not found in Unknown on line 0

..

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/lib/extensions/ext/pdo_mysql.so' -
>   dlopen(/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/lib/extensions/ext/pdo_mysql.so,
>   9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib Referenced from:
>   /Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/lib/extensions/ext/pdo_mysql.so Reason:
>   image not found in Unknown on line 0

..

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/lib/extensions/ext/pdo_pgsql.so' -
>   dlopen(/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/lib/extensions/ext/pdo_pgsql.so,
>   9): Library not loaded: /Applications/AMPPS/extra/lib/libpq.5.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/lib/extensions/ext/pdo_pgsql.so Reason: no
>   suitable image found. Did find:
>   /Applications/AMPPS/extra/lib/libpq.5.dylib: file too short
>   /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on
>   line 0

Comment: can you try to reset the password?

Comment: "the server rejected the connection" — No, it didn't. It allowed the connection, asked for a username and password, then rejected the ones that were entered.

Comment: cannot reset the password on my mysql in ampps i cannot acces mysql at all

Answer (score -1):

You should find `config.inc.php` file inside phpMyAdmin folder.
Locate a line which looks like this: `cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']`, and set its value to `http`. This way, every time you access phpMyAdmin, it will ask you to specify your mysql username and password.